# /proc/self/maps - 3rd mapped piece of file?

Tags: linux, executable, proc

I'm running Arch linux on my laptop, which is kernel 3.12.9 right now. Something has changed about the way the kernel maps in a dynamically-linked executable and I can't figure it out.  Here's the example:

```
% /usr/bin/cat /proc/self/maps
...
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1186756             /usr/bin/cat
0060a000-0060b000 r--p 0000a000 08:02 1186756             /usr/bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:02 1186756             /usr/bin/cat
00d6c000-00d8d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                   [heap]
7f29b3485000-7f29b3623000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1182988     /usr/lib/libc-2.19.so
...
```

My question is: what is the third mapping from `/usr/bin/cat`?

Based on `readelf -l /usr/bin/cat`, there's a loadable segment of 0x1f8 bytes that should map at 0x400000.  There's a loadable segment of 0xae10 bytes at 0x60ae10. Those two pieces of file correspond to the 00400000-0040b000 mapping, and the 0060a000-0060b000 mapping. But the third mapping, which claims to be at a file offset of 0xb000 bytes, doesn't seem to correspond to any Elf64_Phdr. In fact, the elf header only has 2 PT_LOAD segments.

I read through `fs/binfm_elf.c` in the kernel 3.13.2 source code, and I don't see that the kernel maps in anything other than PT_LOAD segments. If I run `strace -o trace.out /usr/bin/cat /proc/self/maps`, I don't see any `mmap()` calls that would map in a piece of `/usr/bin/cat`, so that 3rd piece is mapped in by the kernel.

I ran the same command (`cat /proc/self/maps`) on a RHEL server that was running kernel 2.6.18 + RH patches. That only shows 2 pieces of /usr/bin/cat mapped into memory, so this might be new with kernel 3.x.

Comment: Just confirming your findings, I noticed the same differences on CentOS 5 (2.6.18-238.19.1.el5). However on CentOS 6 (2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64) it too shows the 3 segments. When reading this I also had the thought if this was something to do with SELinux or security in some way.

Comment: Isn't that code (`.text`), read-only data (`.rodata`), and read-write global data (`.data`)?

Comment: @Gilles - if you do `readelf -h /usr/bin/cat`, you can see that the `.text` and `.rodata` sections end up in the first LOAD segment. `.data` and `.bss` sections end up in the second LOAD segment. This 3rd mapped segment is something else.

Comment: The second mapping can not be .data and .bss since it is read only and those segments are read/write.  @Giles was correct here.  Use `objdump -x` to see the different segments and you should find the .data segment lines up with that third mapping.

Comment: @psusi I'm pretty sure that the `.data` section belongs to the second loadable segment.

Comment: @newbie, again, it can't since the second mapping is read only, and the data segment must be writable.

Comment: @psusi I'm talking about segment in ELF header, not a memory region. The second LOAD segment splits into two memory regions with `r--p` and `rw-p` execute permissions respectively. The question is why does it happen.

Comment: @newbie, because the Sections: header says it is divided into the .got.plt, .data, and .bss segments.

Comment: @psusi - I'm pretty sure that the ELF loader in the kernel doesn't look at the Sections header at all, just the Pheaders.  I'm still confused about this, by the way. I was working on a "userland exec" at the time, and mapping in just the 2 LOAD segments works fine for userland exec

Comment: Based on the observed behavior, the reverse is true: it uses the sections header.  Only paying attention to the segments table works since the only error it introduces is incorrectly granting execute permission to a few sections that don't need it.

Comment: @psusi Take a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/eDkMtdrC) paste. As we can see there are five sections (18-22) which are mapped to the memory region `08054000-08055000 [r--p]`. The weird thing is that these sections have `WA` flags and should be writeable.

Comment: @newbie, that is pretty fscked up.  The .init_array and .fini_array should definitely be read only, as they are actually mapped.  Not sure why the headers says they aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The kernel does map only 2 segments. The third piece is a portion of one of the two loaded by the kernel. The run time linker, the program named in the INTERP pheader, which is /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so for me right now, changes the permissions on the mappings using `mprotect()` so that there are read/write global variables, read-only global variables, and a read/execute text segment. You can see this happen using `strace`, but it's easy to miss, as it's only a single `mprotect()` call.

It wasn't a kernel change that caused this, it was a GNU lib C change.

Answer (score 0):

hi i had the same confuse as you, i had dig the internet and find this, i think this is the answer to your confuse too. link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756119/relationship-between-vma-and-elf-segments

for shrot:

```
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1186756             /usr/bin/cat
**use for store text code and const varibles**

0060a000-0060b000 r--p 0000a000 08:02 1186756             /usr/bin/cat
**use for GNU_RELRO relocated info**

0060b000-0060c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:02 1186756             /usr/bin/cat
use for bss data segment
```

hope this useful